# SQL Query is grabbing double the results

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL Query that is grabbing the *db* for movies. This SQL query is only for showing the users history:

```
$movie = $db2->query("SELECT  m.id AS mid,m.photo AS pho,
       m.destination AS des,m.length AS len,
       m.length_content AS lenc,m.description AS desa,m.rating AS rat,
       m.files AS fil
    FROM  movies m
    INNER JOIN  history h ON h.movie_id = m.id
    WHERE  h.user_id = $id3
    ORDER BY  h.id
    LIMIT  $start, $per_page
```

");

```
while($movie3 = mysqli_fetch_array($movie)) {
           $number++;
             $id2 = $movie3["mid"];
             $photo = $movie3["pho"];
             $destination = $movie3["des"];
             $length = $movie3["len"];
             $length_content = $movie3["lenc"];
             $description = $movie3["desa"];
             $rating = $movie3["rat"];
             $files = $movie3["fil"];

$friends_one = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE number_likes='$id2' LIMIT 2");

 while($movie4 = mysqli_fetch_array($friends_one)) {
...
}
}
```

I have results that are doubling, it is not a problem with the server or db information. This is a photo of the problem:

[image: Visual Aid of SQL Mistake]

This next image is going to show what the results are suppose to look like. This SQL Query follows the same db outline and while loops as history but uses a slightly different SQL query due to the structure of the db.

[image: Visual Aid of Correct Project]

Code Associated with second image:

```
$movie = $db2->query("SELECT  *
    FROM  movies m
    INNER JOIN  likes h ON h.number_likes = m.id
    WHERE  h.user = $id3
    ORDER BY  h.id
    LIMIT  $start, $per_page");

while($movie3 = mysqli_fetch_array($movie)) {
           $number++;
           $id2 = $movie3["id"];
           $photo = $movie3["photo"];
           $rating = $movie3["rating"];
           $destination = $movie3["destination"];
            $length = $movie3["length"];
            $length_content = $movie3["length_content"];
            $files = $movie3["files"];
           $description = $movie3["description"];

 $friends_one = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE number_likes='$id2' LIMIT 2");

           while($movie4 = mysqli_fetch_array($friends_one)) {
...
}
}
```

**I realize this is difficult to figure out. I'm new at programming and appreciate any help given...**

**EDIT: DDL For PhpmyAdmin**

I'm not not quite sure if I did this right. Here are my results:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.4.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Mar 15, 2016 at 12:30 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.26
-- PHP Version: 5.6.12

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `crave crap`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `episodes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `episodes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `show_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `destination` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `length` text NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `friends`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `grab` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `friends`
--

INSERT INTO `friends` (`id`, `user`, `grab`) VALUES
(13, 52, 51),
(14, 53, 51),
(15, 54, 51),
(16, 55, 51);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `history`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=90 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `history`
--

INSERT INTO `history` (`id`, `user_id`, `movie_id`) VALUES
(80, 51, 7),
(81, 51, 8),
(82, 51, 9),
(83, 51, 11),
(84, 51, 11),
(85, 51, 11),
(86, 51, 11),
(87, 51, 11),
(88, 51, 11),
(89, 51, 11);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `likes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `likes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number_likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `review` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=150 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `likes`
--

INSERT INTO `likes` (`id`, `user`, `number_likes`, `review`) VALUES
(130, 51, 9, 'gtgtgt'),
(131, 51, 8, 'gbgtrgrt'),
(132, 52, 8, 'tgrrgrgt'),
(135, 53, 8, 'tgrgtrgtr'),
(136, 53, 9, 'gtbrgtrgtrgtr'),
(137, 52, 11, 'tgrgtrgtr'),
(138, 53, 11, 'tgrgtrgtr'),
(139, 54, 11, 'tgrtgrbgtr'),
(140, 52, 12, 'tgrtgrgtr'),
(141, 53, 12, 'gtrgtrgtr'),
(143, 52, 9, 'ttrgth'),
(146, 51, 7, 'gtgtrtg'),
(147, 52, 7, 'tgtrgtrtr'),
(149, 51, 11, 'No Review Found');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `movies`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `photo` text NOT NULL,
  `destination` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `rating` text NOT NULL,
  `length` text NOT NULL,
  `length_content` text NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `files` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `movies`
--

INSERT INTO `movies` (`id`, `title`, `photo`, `destination`, `description`, `rating`, `length`, `length_content`, `likes`, `files`) VALUES
(7, 'Star Inside Out', 'covers/pirate.jpg', 'movies/56c7ede7d3ed3658.44679765.mp4', 'Professional, Clean, Ready to Go', 'G', '1h 20m', '1', 6, 3),
(8, 'Star Wars', 'covers/star wars.jpg', 'movies/56c7ede7d3ed3108.44679765.mp4', 'Thirty years after the defeat of the Galactic Empire, the galaxy faces a new threat from the evil Kylo Ren (Adam Driver) and the First Order. When a defector named Finn crash-lands on a desert planet, he meets Rey (Daisy Ridley), a tough scavenger whose droid contains a top-secret map. Together, the young duo joins forces with Han Solo (Harrison Ford) to make sure the Resistance receives the intelligence concerning the whereabouts of Luke Skywalker (Mark Hamill), the last of the Jedi Knights.', 'PG', '2h 16m', '1', 100, 100),
(9, 'Hello', 'covers/56e068530dc9f9.52895782.jpg', 'movies/56e06853166618.33290858.mp4', 'Hello', 'PG-13', '58m', '0', 27, 12),
(11, 'The lost boy', 'covers/56e4341b6bb3f5.36887672.jpg', 'movies/56e4341b6bd319.33767547.mp4', 'A boy gets lost in the forest, separating him from his family, he must learn how to survive long enough to get out alive.', 'PG-13', '1h 47m', '1', 29, 58),
(12, 'The lost boy', 'covers/56e4341b6bb3f5.36887672.jpg', 'movies/56e4341b6bd319.33767547.mp4', 'A boy gets lost in the forest, separating him from his family, he must learn how to survive long enough to get out alive.', 'PG-13', '1h 47m', '1', 30, 60),
(14, 'The lost boy', 'covers/56e4341b6bb3f5.36887672.jpg', 'movies/56e4341b6bd319.33767547.mp4', 'A boy gets lost in the forest, separating him from his family, he must learn how to survive long enough to get out alive.', 'PG-13', '1h 47m', '1', 33, 60),
(15, 'The lost boy', 'covers/56e4341b6bb3f5.36887672.jpg', 'movies/56e4341b6bd319.33767547.mp4', 'A boy gets lost in the forest, separating him from his family, he must learn how to survive long enough to get out alive.', 'PG-13', '1h 47m', '1', 30, 60),
(16, 'The lost boy', 'covers/56e4341b6bb3f5.36887672.jpg', 'movies/56e4341b6bd319.33767547.mp4', 'A boy gets lost in the forest, separating him from his family, he must learn how to survive long enough to get out alive.', 'PG-13', '1h 47m', '1', 34, 60),
(17, 'The lost boy', 'covers/56e4341b6bb3f5.36887672.jpg', 'movies/56e4341b6bd319.33767547.mp4', 'A boy gets lost in the forest, separating him from his family, he must learn how to survive long enough to get out alive.', 'PG-13', '1h 47m', '1', 32, 60),
(18, 'The lost boy', 'covers/56e4341b6bb3f5.36887672.jpg', 'movies/56e4341b6bd319.33767547.mp4', 'A boy gets lost in the forest, separating him from his family, he must learn how to survive long enough to get out alive.', 'PG-13', '1h 47m', '1', 32, 60);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `shows`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shows` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `photo` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seasons` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `shows`
--

INSERT INTO `shows` (`id`, `title`, `photo`, `description`, `likes`, `seasons`) VALUES
(1, 'Age of Ultron', 'covers/56c6961452b097.49801377.jpg', 'Hello', 5, 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `show_likes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `show_likes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number_likes` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` text NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `dropbox_token` text NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `premium` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `dropbox_token`, `active`, `premium`, `avatar`) VALUES
(51, 'MatthewMalan', '76a7289eb67f6468356cba907809f2fd', 'kLQQAh1zJSAAAAAAAAABjaQvSFyq0RxKylBPtSL3-PM7uKRDaATZunClQ1Zsv24F', 0, 1, 'avatars/matthew.jpg'),
(52, 'Sam Coles', '91d9dfc1fef07bbcf46fe06f659e8cb3', 'kLQQAh1zJSAAAAAAAAAB48QKdqo-X0nN99I_3bxbFMKRtSdwbsrBz00yO_0P0XAB', 0, 1, 'avatars/sam.jpg'),
(53, 'Traek Malan', '91d9dfc1fef07bbcf46fe06f659e8cb3', 'kLQQAh1zJSAAAAAAAAAB48QKdqo-X0nN99I_3bxbFMKRtSdwbsrBz00yO_0P0XAB', 0, 1, 'avatars/traek.jpg'),
(54, 'Jesse Gaines', '91d9dfc1fef07bbcf46fe06f659e8cb3', 'kLQQAh1zJSAAAAAAAAAB48QKdqo-X0nN99I_3bxbFMKRtSdwbsrBz00yO_0P0XAB', 0, 1, 'avatars/jessie.jpg'),
(55, 'Rich Radford', '91d9dfc1fef07bbcf46fe06f659e8cb3', 'kLQQAh1zJSAAAAAAAAAB48QKdqo-X0nN99I_3bxbFMKRtSdwbsrBz00yO_0P0XAB', 0, 1, 'avatars/rich.jpg'),
(58, 'Donald Trump', '91d9dfc1fef07bbcf46fe06f659e8cb3', 'kLQQAh1zJSAAAAAAAAAB48QKdqo-X0nN99I_3bxbFMKRtSdwbsrBz00yO_0P0XAB', 0, 1, 'avatars/donald.jpg'),
(59, 'Marco Rubio', '91d9dfc1fef07bbcf46fe06f659e8cb3', 'kLQQAh1zJSAAAAAAAAAB48QKdqo-X0nN99I_3bxbFMKRtSdwbsrBz00yO_0P0XAB', 0, 1, 'avatars/marco.jpg'),
(62, 'Joseph Malan', '91d9dfc1fef07bbcf46fe06f659e8cb3', 'kLQQAh1zJSAAAAAAAAAB5mCiOhnPi2nNKr7bhFLnOC8LVRMiLvdI30CNgSJNOygm', 0, 1, 'default');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `episodes`
--
ALTER TABLE `episodes`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `friends`
--
ALTER TABLE `friends`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `history`
--
ALTER TABLE `history`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `likes`
--
ALTER TABLE `likes`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `movies`
--
ALTER TABLE `movies`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `shows`
--
ALTER TABLE `shows`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `show_likes`
--
ALTER TABLE `show_likes`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `episodes`
--
ALTER TABLE `episodes`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `friends`
--
ALTER TABLE `friends`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=17;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `history`
--
ALTER TABLE `history`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=90;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `likes`
--
ALTER TABLE `likes`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=150;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `movies`
--
ALTER TABLE `movies`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=19;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `shows`
--
ALTER TABLE `shows`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `show_likes`
--
ALTER TABLE `show_likes`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=63;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

**EDIT @trincot**

This is the code I used:

```
$movie = $db2->query("SELECT  m.id AS mid, m.photo AS pho,
        m.destination AS des, m.length AS len,
        m.length_content AS lenc, m.description AS desa, m.rating AS rat,
        m.files AS fil
    FROM  movies m
    INNER JOIN  
      ( SELECT  movie_id, MAX(id) AS id,
            FROM  history
            WHERE  h.user_id = $id3
            GROUP BY  movie_id 
      ) h ON h.movie_id = m.id
    ORDER BY  h.id
    LIMIT  $start, $per_page");
```

`$movie` connects to a while loop. `$id3` is the users id, which is found by a session. `$start` and `$per_page` are used for pagination purposes.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: @tadman I completely agree. I generally add security to my site as the last step. I first focus on the front and back end interface. What's the point of securing something that doesn't work?

Comment: Can you provide DDL for tables.

Comment: What's the point of programming something *properly* so you don't battle quoting bugs later? Do it the right way, it shows you're taking an interest in following best practices and being careful. Don't take short-cuts here and complain your broken code doesn't work.

Comment: @ryantxr I apologize for my lack of knowledge. What does DDL refer to?

Comment: I need to see your table definitions. `CREATE TABLE ...`

Comment: Like table names, rows, columns, etc?

Comment: I use PhpMyAdmin for creating, selecting and viewing tables. It creates the tables for me. Do you want more info or a screenshot of the info found in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: DDL is (are) the commands used to create your tables and other db internals. You have a complex question. It's hard for people to reply to a complex query. I suggest you set up a fiddle, and provide a link in your Q. People are much more responsive to fiddles, because they can touch actual code. (google mysql fiddle if you've never heard of it)

Comment: PHPMyAdmin will give you the DDL for a table. We need to see how the tables are related.  And sample data would help also.

Comment: Is your problem the little avatars on bottom that show up several times after the 4th movie? Could you give the user_id that you used on this pic? I loaded your DB and I'd like to reproduce your queries exactly

Comment: @ThomasG Yes, this is the problem. The problem starts at the 4th movie and continues with the other movies. The id is 84 for the 4th movie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The duplicates

The DDL section shows you have duplicates in the `history` table, which in itself is not a problem, but it does explain the duplicate results you get in your query.

The solution is to filter away the duplicate history records, and keep only the most recent from them for the rest of the query. This filtering you can do in a sub query, like this:

```
SELECT      m.id AS mid,
            m.photo AS pho, 
            m.destination AS des,
            m.length AS len,
            m.length_content AS lenc,
            m.description AS desa,
            m.rating AS rat,
            m.files AS fil 
FROM        movies m 
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT   movie_id,
                         MAX(id) AS id 
                FROM     history 
                WHERE    user_id = ?
                GROUP BY movie_id
            ) h ON h.movie_id = m.id
ORDER BY    h.id 
LIMIT       ?, ?
```

(If SQL fiddle is willing to work, here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/857b35/5)).

The essence is in the `GROUP BY movie_id` which ensures you will not get duplicate movies. At the same time you take the greatest *id* from that group, which corresponds to the most recent one of that group, and this is important for the outer `ORDER BY`.

The question marks are place holders to be replaced when you prepare the statement (see below).

In the second version of the query, you don't select from `history`, but from `likes`. I assume you really want to select from `history`. If however, you want to only show movies that appear for this user in the `likes` table, you must either make sure the combination of movie and user is unique in that table, or apply the same principle as above, i.e. perform a sub query.

#### Prepared statements

You should use prepared statements to avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Here is how you would do it:

```php
$sql = ' ... '; // insert above query here
$stmt_movies = $db2->prepare($sql);
$stmt_movies->bind_param("iii", $user_id, $start, $per_page);
$stmt_movies->execute() or die($stmt_movies->error);
$stmt_movies->store_result();
$stmt_movies->bind_result($movie_id, $photo, $destination, $length,
                   $length_content, $description; $rating, $files);
while ($stmt_movies->fetch()) {
    //...
}
$stmt_movies->free_result();
```

#### The second query

It is really confusing to use the name *number_likes* for a column that apparently holds a movie id. I would recommend to change that name to *movie_id*. The fact that it concerns a like is already apparent from the table name.

Secondly, it is just as confusing to select from the table *likes* and then call the result *$friends_one*. As far as I can tell a record in the table *likes* indicates that a user likes a certain movie, and potentially records a review written by that user. It does not have any information about friends... A better name would be *$movie_likers*.

You limit the number of records to two, but have no control over which two will be taken. It would be better if you would add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Finally, you should either combine this query with the main query, or at least prepare it, so it is compiled once, and not in every iteration. Here is how that would look (with some change to variable names, see below):

```php
$sql = "SELECT review FROM likes WHERE number_likes = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2";
$stmt_likes = $db2->prepare($sql);
$stmt_likes->bind_param("i", $move_id);
```

Then combined with the other code, you get this code:

```php
$sql = ' ... '; // insert above query here
$stmt_movies = $db2->prepare($sql);
$stmt_movies->bind_param("iii", $movie_id, $start, $per_page);
$stmt_movies->execute() or die($stmt_movies->error);
$stmt_movies->store_result();
$stmt_movies->bind_result($movie_id, $photo, $destination, $length,
                   $length_content, $description; $rating, $files);

$sql = "SELECT review FROM likes WHERE number_likes = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2";
$stmt_likes = $db2->prepare($sql);

while ($stmt_movies->fetch()) {
    $stmt_likes->bind_param("i", $movie_id);
    $stmt_likes->execute() or die($stmt_likes->error);
    $stmt_likes->store_result();
    $stmt_likes->bind_result($review);
    while ($stmt_likes->fetch()) {
        //... 
    }
    $stmt_likes->free_result();
    //...
}
$stmt_movies->free_result();
```

#### Choose telling variable names

As already hinted above, the names of the variables should better not be *$id3*, *$id2*, *$movie4*, ... etc. Try to use more telling names, like *user_id*, *movie_id*, etc. It helps to understand the code -- especially when you come back to it after a few months.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort. However, the query is now making no results appear. I have updated my question to show what code I used. Thanks!

Comment: There were two typos in  the inner query : a comma too many at the end of the select list, and the wrong use of the "h" alias (should be removed). Please check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/857b35/5) (if SQL fiddle is not overloaded). Also note you can break a string over multiple lines in PHP, so you can format your SQL string nicely.

Comment: Did this work for you? Could you give some feed-back?

Comment: Went camping for weekend, sorry for late response. This answer worked perfectly: +1, accept answer and reward bounty...

Answer (score 0):

The first query joins the `history` table, but does not select from it. So you receive as many records per movie as there are history entries for the movie.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the query has a column from the history table in the select. The JOIN for history establishes how the tables are joined.

Comment: @devio Would you mind explaining how you select with a joined SQL selector as you have said? I can test your code. Ryantxr is saying this code won't work...

Comment: @devio I think you have a point. After two of the movies, they all display the same amount of user avatars. Can you help me solve the rest of the problem? I'm new at code and I apologize if the solution is simple in practice...